# "Mon oppression est due à votre identité et à vos droits, qui me manquent." vs "Votre identité et vos droits, qui me manquent, m'oppressent."

Tags: grammaire, stylistique, espagnol

1. *Mon oppression est due à votre identité et à vos droits, qui me manquent.*
2. *Votre identité et vos droits, qui me manquent, m'oppressent.*

Laquelle des deux phrases est correcte ?
C'est un commentaire amer de la part d'une personne, comme moi,
qui est exclue de la société, par ex. d'un migrant qui perçoit son oppression comme
le prix à payer pour l'identité nationale et les privilèges juridiques des autochtones.
La phrase qui m'a inspiré est celle qui figure sur cette bannière : [Mi opresión no es tu identidad.](https://twitter.com/movfemmad/status/1396064026703040512).
La personne veut dire quelque chose comme : Vos droits, les droits que je n'ai pas et votre identité
sont les causes de mon oppression, mais si possible d'une manière plus courte - pour insérer une bannière.
La personne manque des deux (identité et droits) mais éprouve du ressentiment uniquement pour les droits
qui lui manquent.
Laquelle des deux phrases est incorrecte ?

Comment: Tu es sûr que A ayant une identité, est la "cause" de l'oppression de B? A ne devrait donc pas avoir d'identité, pour ne pas "causer" l'oppression de B?

Comment: Ta dernière phrase dit qu'il n'y a de ressentiment que pour l'absence de droits, mais les deux phrases que tu proposes expriment le ressentiment  pour les droits **et** l'identité, il faut clarifier.  *Manquer* le convient pas ici,  "je n'ai pas..." sera probablement mieux. Et pour l'autre verbe je suggère *opprimer* (et pas oppresser), voir [Sens et emploi de opprimer et de oppresser](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/22038/le-vocabulaire/paronymes/sens-et-emploi-de-opprimer-et-de-oppresser).

Comment: @Frank Yes I'm sure, e.g. A having a national identity (American) and living in the US stops B from entering the US (and thus oppresses B) - as B is a Mexican to be deported from the US.

Comment: La bannière dit aussi "Tu sexo no determina tu personnalidad" (*Ta personnalité ne se réduit pas à ton sexe*). Dans ce contexte, "Mi opresión no es tu identidad", (*l'oppression de la femme n'est pas ce qui doit vous caractériser*) signifie plutôt que la phallocratie n'est pas le propre de l'homme.

Comment: A partir de la précision indiquée en commentaire,, "Votre identité et vos droits" correspond à "Votre statut et vos privilèges". Ainsi, le protestataire pourrait dire "*Votre statut et vos privilèges ne justifient pas mon asservissement*".

Comment: @Graffito Dans "Tu sexo no determina tu personnalidad", on pourrait aussi noter le verbe _determinar_, et le retenir pour interpréter que ta personnallité n'est pas _déterminée_ par ton sexe, ie tu peux avoir n'importe quel sexe et assumer n'importe quelle personnalité.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Laquelle des deux phrases est correcte ?*

Le deux phrases sont grammaticalement correctes mais sont peu ou pas compréhensibles.

Voici comment on pourrait exprimer cette idée :

> Votre identité et vos droits, en être privé m'opprime.

Après réflexion, le sens attendu est probablement plus proche de celui-ci :

> Je n'ai ni votre identité, ni les droits qui en découlent. Je suis opprimé étant privé de ces derniers.

Comment: Je crois que l'intention est plus directement d'impliquer que les droits des uns oppressent les autres. Ce n'est peut-être pas une maladresse dans l'utilisation de la langue, mais bien l'intention: de dire que certains ont des droits qui sont bel et bien _la cause_ d'une oppression, plutôt qu'un manque de droits qui est une oppression. Quoique... la deuxième phrase citée par l'OP va plutôt dans ton sens.

Comment: La maladresse se situe dans les mots utilisés. *Qui me manquent* a plusieurs sens. On ne sait pas trop quoi comprendre quand ça s'applique à des droits ou une identité. J'ai retenu ce que j'ai compris de la dernière phrase. Seul l'OP pourra *adjudiquer* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Le sens du propos peut être difficile à cerner, surtout que la banderole en espagnol citée en exemple veut dire l'inverse de "ton identité est mon oppression".

Si le but est de délivrer un message court et percutant, j'omettrais l'aspect "droits *qui me manquent*" qui est tout à fait présent implicitement. Quelque chose comme :

> Votre identité, mon oppression
>
> Egalité des droits

ou simplement

> Votre identité
>
> Vos droits
>
> Mon oppression

A noter que "*ton* identité" - comme dans la banderole - sera peut-être perçu comme moins agressif que "*votre* identité" puisqu'on interroge directement le récepteur en tant qu'individu avec un tutoiement qui rapproche, au lieu de s'opposer frontalement à la masse, à une foule de personnes qui ont ces droits.